# The specified domain does not exist or could not be contacted

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

If the program runs as a domain account, then everything works fine if from a local account on the line `checkEntry.Name.ToString();` then exception **The specified domain does not exist or could not be contacted.**

```
DirectoryEntry checkEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=MyDomain,dc=com", @"MyDomain\MyUser", "MyPassword", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
checkEntry.Name.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can there be pending updates (Windows Update)?

I get this all the time if updates ar waiting to install.

After a reboot everything works fine again.

Comment: We solved this problem by the introduction of computers in the domain